# How to extend Object in JavaScript without losing the original functionality

Tags: javascript, object, implementation

I have a JavaScript object defined like so:

```
var Object = (function () {
    function Object() {
        this.id = RandomNumber();
    }

    // Custom Object.prototype / Object impementations here...

    return Object;
})();
```

The problem is that once this has been constructed, it loses original functionality like `Object.defineProperty` etc.

The idea is that I want to extend the basic functionality of Object, not re-write or overwrite the existing prototype.

How can this be achieved?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I know I can do this without affecting the original functionality:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function() { }
```

but I need to specifically add functionality to Object's constructor, i.e.

```
function Object() { this.id = 0; }
```

The new functionality must not overwrite the original Functionality.

Comment: Don't override the Object constructor. It won't work for object literals, and may cause a lot of side-effects. Why not just create a CustomObject constructor instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.prototype` to add a property:

```
Object.prototype.specialMethod = function () {
    // Your method's code
};
```

And you'd use it like:

```
var a = {};
a.specialMethod();
```

Although I would discourage adding a property to the `Object`'s prototype, because it is enumerable and will mess up looping, and will be inherited by all objects, and objects that inherit from `Object`, which is basically everything.

You could actually use the `Object.defineProperty` method you mention:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "specialMethod", {
    enumerable: false,    // The important one, to avoid looping problems
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function () {
        // Your method's code
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I mean. I was not clear enough, so I will update my question. Basically, I need to add functionality to the Object constructor i.e. var x = new Object() will do whatever Object does, including what I want it to do.

Comment: @series0ne Ahh I see, sorry for the confusion. So you want to be able to automatically do something when you use something like `var x = new Object();`? Like always set a property on the newly created object, without having to explicitly do it in your main code every time?

Comment: Exactly. I've since found that what I am trying to do is virtually impossible as it seems to ruin JavaScript's inheritance, so using the prototype seems to be the only option, however this exposes a variable to the user that I don't want, but there is no other way around it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend this object you should create another object that has its prototype assigned a new instance of Object.

```
var Object = (function () {
    function Object() {
        this.id = 5;
    }

    Object.prototype.speak = function(prop){
       alert(this[prop]);
    }

    return Object;
})();

function ExtendsObject(prop){
    this.someProperty = prop;
}

ExtendsObject.prototype = new Object();

var xObj = new ExtendsObject("derived");
xObj.speak("id");
xObj.speak("someProperty");
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RbCcA/

If you want to stick with the self executing functions here is the example rewrote:

```
var Object = (function () {
    function Object() {
        this.id = 5;
    }

    Object.prototype.speak = function(prop){
       alert(this[prop]);
    }

    return Object;
})();

var ExtendsObject = (function(){

    function ExtendsObject(prop){
       this.someProperty = prop;
    }

    ExtendsObject.prototype = new Object();

    return ExtendsObject;
})();

var xObj = new ExtendsObject("derived");
xObj.speak("id");
xObj.speak("someProperty");
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RbCcA/1/

I do question the use of self executing functions in this situation.  They are usually used to encapsulate and shield internals, however in the code example they are being exposed by returning the object from the SEF.  Returning the object and storing it in a global variable just re-exposes the object, allowing its prototype and properties to be manipulated.  Maybe there are private variables you have not mentioned, but as stated I find the SEFs unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Ian wrote. If you also want to check it the method already exists use

```
if (Object.prototype.specialMethod == null) Object.prototype.specialMethod = function() { ... };
```